# Programmatically (not declaratively) render Meteor template

Tags: meteor, fullcalendar

I'm trying to customize events added to FullCalendar, using `eventRender`. I'm aware that I can directly return HTML from my `eventRender` method, but I would prefer to programmatically merge event data with a predefined Meteor template (with associated events).

Previously I could have used `Meteor.render()` but that functionality is no longer available. I'm familiar with `Template.dynamic`, but that appear to only be available declaratively, and most of the questions I've seen here are quite old, so refer to deprecated functionality.

Here's what I would like to do:

**Calendar - event population & rendering:**

```
Template.dashboard.rendered = function(){
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
      callback(Events.find().fetch()); 
    },

    eventRender: function(event, element) {
      // PROGRAMMATICALLY RENDER TEMPLATE
      // The following does not work - no data is attached 
      return Template.calendarEvent.renderFunction(event);
    }
  });
};
```

**Event template HTML**

```
<template name="calendarEvent">
  {{title}} 
  <!-- full layout for rendering event here -->
</template>
```

**Event template JS**

```
Template.calendarEvent.events({
  // define template event handlers
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That function was not removed, it was renamed and quite a while ago it also changed behaviour (when spark was replaced by blaze).

What you are looking for is [Blaze.renderWithData](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/blaze_renderwithdata).

Note that it returns a `Blaze.View` and not a DOM object.

To make it a dom object you could provide it as a parent:

```
var renderedCalendarEvent = document.createElement("div");

Blaze.renderWithData(Template.calenderEvent, event, renderedCalendarEvent);
```

The DOM element `renderedCalendarEvent` will react to any reactive sources the template uses.

If you need HTML you can use [Blaze.toHTMLWithData](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/blaze_tohtmlwithdata), but that html will remain static.

```
Blaze.toHTMLWithData(Template.calenderEvent, event);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect. Much appreciated. I've been away from this project for a few months, and Meteor has changed quite a bit in the interim. I haven't had an opportunity to familiarize myself with the new Blaze landscape yet.

Comment: It looks like events are not connected up properly when using Blaze.renderWithData() or Blaze.render().  Is this true, or my bug I wonder?

Comment: @MichaelGraff events should be working fine with `.render()` and `.renderWithData()`, but not with `.toHTMLWithData()`.

Comment: I agree it should, but it doesn't seem to for me.  I've filed a github issue with the meteor crowd; I'll update this as I get more info or find out it was my bug.

Comment: @MichaelGraff can you post a link to the github issue?

Comment: @MichaelGraff Tried to reproduce, but couldn't: http://meteorpad.com/pad/b3HQcw5NNkcXXysFE/Leaderboard

Comment: @MichaelGraff could you post a link to the github issue?

Comment: I think (as others do), this is an interaction with google maps and meteor.  I'll post more when the problem occurs again in some later project.  :)